# Why is this for loop giving me an incorrect output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I have a function that tells me the factors of a number, then should print how many it has.

```
factors = 0

def getFactors(n):
    global factors
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i==0:
            print(i)
            factors += 1
    print(n, "has", factors, "factors.")
```

However, the number of factors seems to be wrong. Apparently 16 has 6 factors even though it clearly lists 4.

```
>>> getFactors(16)
1
2
4
8
16 has 6 factors.
>>>
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: You don't need to go the whole way to `n`. Obviously, a factor cannot be greater than `n/2`. Thus you can spare a half of iterations with `range(1, n/2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the first time you call `getFactors(16)` you will correctly get `4`. The problem is likely that you've called the function multiple times, and since you used `global factors`, the value of `factors` isn't reset to `0` each time you call the function. The global variable keeps being mutated each time you call the function.

If you remove the `global` variable and make it function local it will work fine

```
def getFactors(n):
    factors = 0
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i==0:
            print(i)
            factors += 1
    print(n, "has", factors, "factors.")

>>> getFactors(16)
1
2
4
8
16 has 4 factors.
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, I completely forgot it needed to be reset.

Comment: @Eddie If instead of printing the factors you want to return them, you can turn the function to one line as `return [i for i in range(1,n) if n%i == 0]` (or use yield, of course)